# insert multiple values from one table to another

Tags: c#, mysql, insert-into

I want to insert multiple rows with different value into one table from anthor table which have some device_id but it gives error this is my query

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ind_master(ind,device_id) SELECT ind FROM schedule_days WHERE device_id = '"+DBdevice_id+"','"+DBdevice_id+"'", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, and please do not write inline queries. Google "SQL Injection".

Comment: @Stanley_A:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''25'' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ind_master(ind,device_id) SELECT ind,'"+DBdevice_id+"' FROM schedule_days WHERE device_id = '"+DBdevice_id+"'", con);
```

if device_id is integer, then remove the single quotes ''